# Image Wrapping Pandoc Latex output

Tags: graphics, wrap

I use pandoc markdown to convert markdown text to pdf. My requirement is to have running text with bullet points to the right and image to the left. I tried with pandoc inline image and it did not work as expected.

Any help or pointers appreciated on this.

On latex I use Xelatex engine on Mac.[image]

**Edit**

**Pandoc Markup**

```
\sectionbreak

## Demo Page

\begin{wrapfigure}[14]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=3.0in,keepaspectratio].  {Demo.jpg}\end{center}
\caption{Basic layout}
\end{wrapfigure}

### Demo Content - Checking for Image Wrap

__Some Weird Content__

We will show something on related to Image Wrapping

__Example__

* Apple Store Screenshot
* Demo Content for filling this page

__UI Component__

1. *Title*: Title of the App that you are looking.  This content is cooked for this sample
2. *App Name*: What is that app name you are looking for?
3. *Tabs*: Are you sure you are on the right tab? If not pick the right tab
4. *Image*: right image of the screenshot
5. *Video*: If it is applicable for this section place it here
```

**Tex Generated from Pandoc**

```
\sectionbreak

\subsection{Demo Page}\label{demo-page}

\begin{wrapfigure}[14]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=3.0in,keepaspectratio]{Demo.jpg}\end{center}
\caption{Basic layout}
\end{wrapfigure}

\subsubsection{Demo Content - Checking for Image Wrap}\label{demo-content---checking-for-image-wrap}

\textbf{Some Weird Content} We will show something on related to Image Wrapping

\textbf{Example}

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
Apple Store Screenshot
\item
Demo Content for filling this page
\end{itemize}

\textbf{UI Component}

\begin{enumerate}
\def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\tightlist
\item
\emph{Title}: Title of the App that you are looking. This content is
cooked for this sample
\item
\emph{App Name}: What is that app name you are looking for?
\item
\emph{Tabs}: Are you sure you are on the right tab? If not pick the
right tab
\item
\emph{Image}: right image of the screenshot
\item
\emph{Video}: If it is applicable for this section place it here
\end{enumerate}
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

Comment: [Welcome!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/34551) Could you provide us a [minimal woking example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/34551): a simple `markdown` code, with the command you use to convert it into `pdf`, and a description of what you get, and of what you want? We only know what you want.

Comment: (Also, keep in mind that markdown is a tool to write your content easily, but not really well-suited to tweak the way it will be displayed: you may need to edit your `.tex` by hand to obtain a particular layout)

Comment: @Clément - I absolutely agree that we can get markdown to a certain extent.  Also I have updated the question with MWE.  Problem is that it looks good with this content.  However, I can't add multiple images and also the page flowing to the next screen is having the image broken.  Any pointers or help appreciated.

Comment: @AbrahamDurairaj: What you've drawn on paper seems a bit easier than what you've supplied in markdown. For example, you're referring to a *list* in your pen/paper drawing, but your example code inserts a sectional unit. These are handled differently when setting a document.

Comment: @Werner - The code is generated by Pandoc as supplied through markdown.  I am trying to control them through template.  As mentioned in my earlier comment I am trying to see the possibility of adding multiple images and image not broken when it goes beyond the page size to the next page. I am newbie to tex.